# Unable to get custom context processor to be invoked

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-context

I am trying to create a custom context processor which will render a list of menu items for a logged in user. I have done the following:

---

Within my settings.py I have

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSOR = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'mysite.accounts.context_processors.user_menu',
)
```

Under the accounts submodule I have **`context_processors.py`** with the following, for now:

```
def user_menu(request):
    return {'user_menu':'Hello World'}
```

On my template page I have the following:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
Menu
{{user_menu}}
{% endif %}
```

The invoking view is as follows:

```
def profile(request):
    return render_to_response('accounts/profile.html',context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

However I am unable to get the `{{user_menu}}` to render anything on the page, I know the user is authenticated as other sections of the template with similar checks render correctly. Am I missing something here. Please help
Thank you

**Edit:** Thanks Ben, Daniel, I have fixed the (S) in `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSOR`,  however Django now has trouble resolving the module and I get the following message

```
Error importing request processor module django.contrib.auth.context_processors: "No module named context_processors"
```

**UPDATE:** I fixed it by changing the path to `django.core.context_processors.auth` Seems like the modules have been moved around

Comment: It should be `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The setting name should be `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`, with an S.

Comment: Ah, Thanks... :p.. I seem to have progressed a bit more now I get the following error.. Sorry I am a newbie to both python and django
Error importing request processor module django.contrib.auth.context_processors: "No module named context_processors"

Comment: Says you fixed it by make sure every folder you create with python code has a __init__.py in it.  That tells python, yo, it's a module.